# Dynamically change tab activity when click the button in another tab that triggers input focusing

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, tabs

I have tab pane like this

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
<li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
<div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="n_pimpinan">TEXT :</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="n_pimpinan" name="n_pimpinan" placeholder="text">
        <button type="text" class="btn btn-default" id="button" name="button" >Click ME</button>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
   <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="n_pimpinan">TEXT 2:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="n_pimpinan2" name="n_pimpinan2" placeholder="text">
        <button type="text" class="btn btn-default" id="button" name="button2" >Click ME 2</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

how do i make if i clicked button[name="button"] it will direct me to Tab **Menu 1** and focusin **input[name="n_pimpinan2"]** using jquery? so the tab would change the active tab from **Home** tab to **Menu 1** tab without using javascript attribute tab pane clicked.

i have made some javascript like this

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    $('input[name="n_pimpinan2"]').focusin();
});
```

but it doesnt direct me to another tab ( **Menu 1** )

many thanks

Comment: did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.tab('show')` and jquery `.focus()` methods to achieve your goal like following.

```js
$('#button').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.nav-tabs a[href="#menu1"]').tab('show');
    $('input[name="n_pimpinan2"]').focus();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li style="margin-left:20px"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
<div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="n_pimpinan">TEXT :</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="n_pimpinan" name="n_pimpinan" placeholder="text">
        <button type="text" class="btn btn-default" id="button" name="button" >Click ME</button>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
   <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="n_pimpinan">TEXT 2:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="n_pimpinan2" name="n_pimpinan2" placeholder="text">
        <button type="text" class="btn btn-default" id="button" name="button2" >Click ME 2</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but the tab pane seems broken, when i clicked home again, it didn't change the content,

Comment: when i clicked the button 1 in Home tab, it change the content to tab Menu 1, but when i am trying to clicked again Home tab, it still in Menu 1 content

Comment: @gagantous I have updated my answer. now it works as you wish